# Computing the iterator return type at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

I need a function that takes two arguments `arg1` and `arg2`

```
template<class T1, class T2>
SomeReturnType Foo(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

The arguments can be a pointer or an `std::iterator`, either a bidirectional_iterator of a random_access_iterator. `Foo` does some operation with those iterators and needs to return an iterator to another object, but the returned iterator is of the following type

```
ptr, T   -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
T,   ptr -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
ptr, ptr -> iterator< random_access_iterator_tag >

random_access_iterator, random_access_iterator -> iterator< random_access_iterator_tag >

random_access_iterator, T -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
T, random_access_iterator -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
T, T                      -> iterator< bidirectional_iterator_tag> >
```

I plan to call helper functions from `Foo` based on iterator_category_tags of the arguments, using function overloading to take care of the dispatch. But I dont know how to compute the return type of `Foo`.

EDIT: I see the problem now. The return type of `Foo` is derived from  std::iterator, and can be the argument of the `Foo` function. This is a problem because the traits class that I have been using were not specialized for these return types, only the base classes of the return types. I think the solution is to use the `is derived_from` metafunction.

EDIT2: the title clearly does not reflect the content of the question. To make this useful for others  I am soliciting suggestions for a better title.

Comment: Are you writing `Foo` now and need a way to make it return different objects depending on the input, or does `Foo` exist already and you need know what the return type is in code _outside_ of `Foo`?

Comment: If C++11 is available, consider `decltype`.

Comment: @jogojapan I am writing `Foo` now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you're looking for a way to derive the return type from the argument types, you can do it in the classical way, like following (for the first few cases):

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct ret_iterator {};

// ptr, T   -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
template<typename P, typename T>
struct ret_iterator<P *, T>
{
  typedef std::iterator<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, P> iter;
};

// T,   ptr -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
template<typename T, typename P>
struct ret_iterator<T, P *>
{
  typedef std::iterator<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, P> iter;
};

// ptr, ptr -> iterator< random_access_iterator_tag >
template<typename P>
struct ret_iterator<P *, P *>
{
  typedef std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, P> iter;
};

// random_access_iterator, T -> iterator< iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category >
template<typename T>
struct ret_iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
{
  typedef std::iterator<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, T> iter;
};

template<typename P, typename T>
struct ret_iterator<std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, P>, T>
{
  typedef typename ret_iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::iter iter;
};
```

Comment: This is pretty much what i had, except that the value_type is more complicated in my case. The compiler was complaining thaty it cannot see any of the typdefed types, so I thought maybe it doesnt quite work this way. I have to find out why the typedefs arent visible though i am using structs and not classes. I conjecture that inheritance is getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boost function traits for this.
Look here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html

you can use it like this :

```
boost::function_traits<FunctionSignature>::result_type
```